# Python Minimization involving 2D List

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to perform the minimization of a function `f(x)`

```
periods = range(1,11+1)
friends = range(0,7)
i = 0.05



def f(x):

    sum = 0

    for period in periods:
        sum += x[period-1] * (1+i)**(11-period)

    return -sum



optimize.fmin_cg(f, [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])
```

The above is for a single friend, but now we want to do it for 11 friends by adding another dimension to the list `x` to get `x[friend][period-1]` and added a new loop `for friend in friends`.

```
def g(x):

    sum = 0

    for period in periods:
        for friend in friends:
            sum += x[friend][period-1] * (1+i)**(11-period)

    return -sum


optimize.fmin_cg(g, [[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]])
```

However we now get the error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: Note: the second argument to `fmin_cg` is the initial guess / starting point.  Is your starting point really 11-dimensions?

Comment: @jedwards Thanks for catching this as I'm not too familiar with it, I have 11 elements in `friends`, I think that should make the second argument to `fmin_cg` have 11 dimensions?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you're using the wrong function.  In general, you're starting point should be of the same dimensionality as the number of input variables to your function.  If you have 2 input variables, then your starting point should have 2 dimensions, etc.  But in your case, you need an integer for `friend` and `period`, since your using them as list indices.  I'm not sure `fmin_cg` is what you want.  You either want an integer optimization toolkit or simply brute force search the 77 combinations (which won't be very hard or time consuming at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for `fmin_cg`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg) say:

> x0 : ndarray
>
> A user-supplied initial estimate of xopt, the optimal value of x. It must be a **1-D** array of values.

Since the optimizer does not really care about the shape of the array, you can just flatten your `x0` before passing it to `fmin_cg` and reshape it to the desired shape in `g()`, like so:

```
def g(x):

    sum = 0

    x = x.reshape(11, 11)

    for period in periods:
        for friend in friends:
            sum += x[friend, period-1] * (1+i)**(11-period)

    return -sum

x0 = numpy.array([[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], ...])
optimize.fmin_cg(g, x0.flatten())
```

Note that I used a `numpy` array here instead of nested lists. If you are using `scipy` anyway, there's no harm in learning a bit of `numpy` as well. It is also much easier to reshape than nested lists.